# 86 Day Internship in Germany

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, schengen-visas

I am non - eu citizen. I will do voluntary internship in Germany and I will get paid. In order to do that i had to apply bundesagentur. The company applied for me and currently i have Einvernehmen from ZAV. Because of my internship duration I had to apply Schengen visa. My visa came yesterday but company said that you have not got work permit. You cant start without it. I dont know what should i do ? Thank you for answers.

Comment: What type of visa is it? Field: **type**: 'C' or 'D'? What is written in the field **remarks**?

Comment: It is type C visa. Remarks are besuchs geschaft visum / keit nicht gestatet

Comment: You did correctly paraphrase the remarks. But it says that this is a visa for visiting or business, explicitly not for working. So you got the wrong visa.

Comment: Yeah but I cant apply national visa because of 90 day rule as you know. It is like bug because bundesagentur invited me.

Comment: You must apply for a D (National) Visa, with the paper you have from the  ZAV. A D Visa can be issued for **any** period up to 1 year. It is only the C Visa that allows only visits based on the 90 days rule.

Comment: But my ZAV letter includes 86 days so I thought that they will not give me 90+ days visa. Can I apply national visa with this letter? and I guess zav gives permission voluntary internship up to 90 days. (I am not sure about that)

Comment: They can issue a D Visa for less than 90 days if they wanted to. What is important with a National visa is that it can include the permission to work (stated in the **remarks** field) in the country that issued it.

Comment: @Mark Johnson That sounds like an answer :-)

Comment: Thank you @MarkJohnson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What type of visa is it? Field: **type**: 'C' or 'D'? What is written in the field **remarks**?
>
> > It is type C visa. Remarks are besuchs geschaft visum / keit nicht gestatet
> >
> > - "Erwerbstätigkeit nicht gestattet"
> >
> >   - "Gainful employment not permitted"

...

> Yeah but I cant apply national visa because of 90 day rule as you know. It is like bug because bundesagentur invited me.

You must apply for a D (National) Visa, with the paper you have from the ZAV.
A D Visa can be issued for **any** period up to 1 year. It is only the C Visa that allows only visits based on the 90 days rule.

> But my ZAV letter includes 86 days so I thought that they will not give me 90+ days visa. Can I apply national visa with this letter? and I guess zav gives permission voluntary internship up to 90 days. (I am not sure about that)

They can issue a D Visa for less than 90 days if they wanted to. What is important with a National visa is that it can include the permission to work (stated in the **remarks** field) in the country that issued it.